# Normalisation of Lorentzian function proof

Tags: integration, contour-integration

According to WolframMathworld, when we [normalise the Lorentzian function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html), we get the following result:

$\dfrac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{b}{(z-a)^2+b^2} dz = 1$

I'm trying to prove this using complex analysis, but I'm running into issues.

LHS = $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{b}{(z-a)^2+b^2} dz = \dfrac{b}{\pi}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(z-a)-ib} \dfrac{1}{(z-a)+ib} dz $

With a region of absolute convergence $Re(z)>0$ and simple poles at $z=a \pm ib$, residues are:

$z=a-ib$: $\dfrac{1}{-2ib}$

$z=a+ib$: $\dfrac{1}{2ib}$

Then I have

$2\pi i \dfrac{b}{\pi} \displaystyle \sum residues = 0$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use a contour with $\bf{\Im(z)}>0$

Comment: @tired I'm pretty new to complex integration. Could you explain further?

Comment: ur contour of integration should contain the real axis, to reproduce ur original integral. Afterwards u have to close your contour somehow which is easy in this case because the integral conveges in the whole complex plane (except the poles). Therfore make the choice which makes life easiest: A big semicircle in the upper half plane and therefor $\Im(z)>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your closed contour is a half-circle with the diameter on the real line and circular part in the upper-half plane it only contains the pole $a+ib$ assuming $a,b>0$ (as in this case $a-ib$ is in the lower half plane). So the integral becomes $2\pi i{b\over2ib}=\pi$.

Comment: Why does it work when we only look at one of the poles?

Comment: Because while calculating the integral only the poles that are inside your contour count, the poles outside your contour don't affect the integral.

Comment: That's just circular logic.

Comment: The reason is winding number of a curve w.r.t a point that lies outside of it is zero but that's a lot to explain in comments. You should look up the proofs of the theorems you're using.